# Cost and F_score telling different stories

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks

So I created an ANN with 4 nodes hidden layers and 3 nodes in output layer (as there are 3 classes) to classify the following data-set of flowers.

[UCI Iris Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)

Now I tokk 60% of the data and used it to train the ANN. The learning rate for  the connection between both the layers are `0.1`. I have used the `sigmoid` function as the activation function with the conventional cost function and gradient descent (no regularization) with back propagation for learning. More info about it [here.](http://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logistic_regression.html)

So anyways I graphed its cost `J` and its `F_score`. Since there are 3 classes I have calculated `F_score` the following way `(F_score1 + F_score2 + F_score3)/3` where `F_scorei` denotes the `F_score` of `i`th class. So I plotted the `J` and `F_score` only of the training data only not cross validation or test set and got the following 2 graphs for `J` and `F_score` as a function of number of epochs.

[image: Cost as function of epochs]
[image: F_score as function of epochs]

NOTE: X- axis is number of epochs while y-axis is the value of `J` or `F_score`.

Now what is baffles me isthat

- Why is there a sudden spike at about the `1200 - 1400` the epoch in the cost `J`?
- Why is there a mismatch between `J` and `F_score`? Cost is continuously decreasing but `F_score` is not reflecting it?

I printed out the true positives for the 3 classes and found out that the point where `J` is spiking the true positive of one of the classes is suddenly becoming `0`. Why is this happening? Do you think i may have a mistake in my code? But even if I have a mistake why is this ANN performing satisfactorily for first 1000 epochs?

Any help is highly appreciated.